# Align text in center in a command line interface

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Is it possible to align text on the center of the command prompt in Java? I **don't want to** use a fixed number of spaces because it needs to print out a variable that could have a varying amount of characters.

I *could* use a function to determine how many characters the variable has and print spaces accordingly, but that could change depending on the size of the console window. Is there a cross-OS solution to the problem, or should I just assume a fixed width?

Comment: Don't think it is possible if you mean any generic console - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286461/can-i-find-the-console-width-with-java

Comment: @DavidTitarenco - definitely not a duplicate of the linked question.