# Trying to get terminal $COLUMNS in Java

Tags: java, bash, terminal, width, environment-variables

I'm currently trying to get the number of columns the terminal has in Java. For that I know there is an environment variable $COLUMNS, so I try to run 'echo $COLUMNS' and read its output, but for some weird reason I get a value that makes no sense, and on top of that, I always get the same value, no matter how I resize the terminal.

This is my code:

```
public static final String[] COLS = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $COLUMNS </dev/tty"};

    public int getColumns(){
    try{
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CONST.COLS);
        p.waitFor();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
        int cols = in.read();
        return cols;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're redirecting STDIN into your 'echo' command from /dev/tty, which isn't going to work.  What happens if you just type `echo $COLUMNS` at the command line?

Comment: It prints the number of columns. What do I have to do then? Tried without the </dev/tty, still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know Java, so I'm not sure I can really help any more.  However, $COLUMNS is a feature in Bash, not the Bourne shell, so try changing /bin/sh to /bin/bash (or whatever the path on your system is).

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the `tput` command instead.

To get number of columns:

```
tput cols
```

The man page for [tput](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput).

Comment: Same problem, now gives me another value, but still not the correct one and still a constant one.

Comment: Using tput directly won't work. I always get 80. The solution is to use redirection magic. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286461/can-i-find-the-console-width-with-java/18883172#18883172