# Java: Getting command-line size in characters

Tags: java, user-interface, text, command-line-interface

Is there a way to get the size of a command prompt in Java? I want to draw characters on the outside of the prompt 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ1Xu.png) (please see photo)

I've tried using `java.util.Scanner` and it didn't work out too well, to say the least. Does anybody have an idea on how one would come about getting the command prompt's width, height, and font details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a way to get a **console** information (its width, height). You can find more information in this question: [Can I find the console width with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286461/can-i-find-the-console-width-with-java).

If you are **not** looking for a cross-platform solution, that works with all kinds of terminals, you may find [JLine 2](https://github.com/jline/jline2) useful.

Comment: What do you mean 'non-cross platform'?

Comment: It should work on standard Linux, Mac or Windows terminal, though there are some issues with Cygwin console or Eclipse console. Still, it might be good enough for your use case.