# How to print triangle in the center of the console in java?

Tags: java, console, size, character

This is regarding an interview question to print triangle in the center of the console. Is there any way to identify the console size in characters in java? With that how to print the object in the center of the console\screen in java?

Answer (score 0):

You could a curses-like library ([Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/) for instance) to print it.

To print it in the center of console window you'd have to determine it's width, which is [not an easy task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1286677/5922757).