# SHH over virtual terminal not displaying fullscreen terminal editors correctly

Tags: go, ssh, terminal

The goal is to initiate and drive an SSH client programmatically. The current example is in Go, but Typescript/Js is also an option, if that proves to be the better alternative.
The following snippet works as expected for the most part, but it fails when dealing with full-screen terminal editors (e.g. nano). Specifically, the bottom part of the screen is cut off/overlapping with itself, and editing is impossible. (Lines are duplicating, the cursor doesn't move properly, and more)

```
func Connect() {
    // SSH server details
    sshHost := "192.168.1.166"
    sshPort := 22
    sshUser := "user"
    sshPassword := "pass"

    fmt.Printf("Connecting to %s@%s:%d...\n", sshUser, sshHost, sshPort)

    // Create SSH configuration
    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: sshUser,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(sshPassword),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    // Establish SSH connection
    sshAddress := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", sshHost, sshPort)
    sshClient, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", sshAddress, sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to establish SSH connection:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer sshClient.Close()

    // Request a pseudo-terminal
    session, err := sshClient.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create session:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Start a pseudo-terminal session
    err = session.RequestPty("xterm-256color", 80, 40, ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          1,
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to request pseudo-terminal:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // !IO STREAMS
    // Set up stdin, stdout, and stderr
    session.Stderr = os.Stderr
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to set up stdin:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer stdin.Close()

    stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to set up stdout:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    go func() {
        if _, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to copy stdout:", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()

    // Start a shell
    err = session.Shell()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to start shell:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Set terminal size for the remote shell
    fd := int(os.Stdin.Fd())
    state, err := term.MakeRaw(fd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error setting terminal raw mode: ", err)
        return
    }
    defer term.Restore(fd, state)


    sigCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigCh)

    // Wait for interrupt signal
    go func() {
        <-sigCh
        fmt.Println("Received interrupt signal. Cleaning up...")
        term.Restore(fd, state)
        session.Close()
        sshClient.Close()
        os.Exit(0)
    }()

    // Wait for the session to finish
    err = session.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Session failed:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

To my understanding, full-screen editors should be nothing more than a series of escape sequences, similar to other working aspects of the terminal, like coloring.
Why is this then not working as expected? Additionally, what's the best approach when debugging escape sequences?

Comment: Your question is very vague please can you update it to be more specific? For example: I am getting this error message, I have this piece of Code, where am I going wrong? You will find more people will answer your question.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what is vague about it.  I am not getting any error, only unexpected behavior ("but it fails when dealing with full-screen terminal editors [...] Specifically, the bottom part of the screen is cut off/overlapping with itself, and editing is impossible [...]"

The code provided is, to my knowledge, the shortest snippet that can reproduce that behaviour. 

I would love to be more descriptive, but I genuinely don't know what else I can/should provide. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `session.RequestPty("xterm-256color", 80, 40,...` Looks like you're telling the remote system that your terminal is 80 x 40 characters. Is that the actual size of the terminal that you're running the program in?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the editor's behavior sounds like the editor doesn't know the correct height and width in characters of the terminal that you're running the program in. Unix TTYs record a terminal height and width. Programs that care about the terminal size will frequently get it from the TTY settings. For example, when I run `stty -a` on my system, the output includes this line:

```
speed 9600 baud; 24 rows; 80 columns;
```

The code that you posted allocates a PTY (pseudo-TTY) for the remote session by calling `session.RequestPty("xterm-256color", 80, 40,...)`. You're telling the remote system that the terminal displays 80 x 40 characters. Processes like full-screen editors will adjust their output based on  the 80x40 terminal size. If that size isn't accurate, the program's output can be messed up in the way you describe.

You should supply the correct values for terminal height and width when you request the PTY, based on the height and width of the actual terminal that you're running the program in. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1286461/13317) describes several methods for getting the local TTY's size from a java program. For example, you could run `stty -a` or `tput lines` and `tput cols`, then parse the output to get the height and width.